# Is there a method to measure desktop application UI response time?

Tags: c++, performance, user-interface, testing, automation

There are C++ desktop application, and i need to measure UI lags because users say that it sometimes lags. How can i implement this ? Tried to use pywinauto with timer start-stop after actions, but it clicks the elements very slowly. On the other side, tried to use SikuliX, it works faster, but very flaky. And another tried solution is [uberAgent](https://uberagent.com/) but it detects all performance subsidence performance, even what is not needed.

Comment: >> but it clicks the elements very slowly. Timings can be adjusted or zeroed in pywinauto. Which exact timing do you need?

Comment: @VasilyRyabov as fast as possible, but now it find elements slowly, so clicks slowly

Comment: you can use jmeter for getting the page response time. Have you considered this?

Comment: @Temizzi I might be wrong, but JMeter is for web UI. Is it really applicable for desktop GUI? I don't think so.

Comment: @Temizzi i don't think its possible, because app don't have any relations with server etc. Only offline

Answer (score 0):

To speed up the elements search I'd recommend using `.child_window(title="...", control_type="...")` specifications instead of `best_match` names like `app.Dialog.OKButton` which is usually slow. Preliminary filtering by `control_type` is extremely fast because it even doesn't need cross-process interaction while getting title/text requires at least 2 cross-process operations: get length and get text then. So pre-filtered list of elements can dramatically reduce number of text retrievals.

Also pywinauto has little pause after some actions like 0.001 sec. inside `.click_input()`. These pauses can be zeroed in `pywinauto.timings` module but it can make the automation flaky in some cases. So try it at your own risk.